# no vs2010 program workin windows 7

Tags: c#, windows

i have just install windows 7 ultimate edition x32

then i install service pack 1 and frame work 4

now when i try to run any program i had made using VS2010 or VS2008 is there an error

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application
```

i tried to use DependencyWalkthrough program to know what is the error all unworking programs told me that IEShims.dll not found but i found it in C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer so i add this path to PATH environment parameter

then when i tried Dependency Walkthrough again it found the file but give me a warning

```
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

and flag red in two files IEFRAME.DLL and SHLWAPI.DLL and the two files there

what can i do to solve this problem no program work now

Comment: Silly question, but I assume that you've since rebooted? Did you receive any errors during the service pack installation? Is this ONLY for apps you've written in VS? Does Internet Explorer work?

Comment: If you write a "hello world" does that run?

Comment: NO I HAVE NO ERROR IN INSTALLATION 

INTERNET EXPLORER RUN GOOD

Comment: YES FOR PROGRAMS RUN IN VS ONLY ANY PROGRAM LIKE WINRAR , SQL SERVER WORK FINE

Comment: WHEN I TRIED TO MAKE A HELLO WORLD PROJECT IT IS AN ERROR WHILE RUNNING IT

Comment: THE ERROR IS error while trying to run project could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Comment: To extend @JonB's question: does the error happen if you make a "Hello World" CONSOLE application? (ie, no Winforms or XAML api?)

Comment: As @DavidLively said, did you reboot after installing .NET 4?

Comment: Install .NET 3.5 on top. Try it.

Comment: yes console application too make the same error>>>> i made restart after installing .Net4 and i installed .Net 3>5 sp1 from add windows feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was win32 ramit virus + win32 virut virus

now it works well after scanning by kaspersky internet security +nod32 antivirus several times